# when the virtual keypad comes the popover move upward in iPad?

Tags: ipad

when i  type the textfield in popover view it moves upward and hide the some fields in popover view.I want overlap the keyboard in popover.any one knows help me.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere you'll be doing this

```
[[Utilities getAppDelegate].menuPopover presentPopoverFromRect:rect
                                                        inView:self.view 
                                      permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny 
                                                      animated:YES];
```

or something similar. What I did was check where the popup was going to be drawn and if it was too low on the screen I changed the permitted arrow directions to everything except handing below the pin `(UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft || UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight || UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown)`